# Django get objects that have certain ManyToMany relations

Tags: django

suppose we have two models like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

we get a queryset of users:

```
user_qs = User.objects.filter(date_joined__range=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-05'])
```

how can I get the list of Group objects that have all users of `user_qs` in their users?

```
django==3.2
```

**Edit:**

I rephrase my question more accurately:

the `user_qs` gives us some users for example `user_1` and `user_2`.
the groups that I want to get must have both `user_1` and `user_2` in their list of users. if the group has more users besides these two, it is ok and should be included. example:

```
group_1.users.all() = [user_1, user_2]
group_2.users.all() = [user_1, user_3]
group_3.users.all() = [user_1, user_2, user_3, user_4]
group_4.users.all() = [user_2, user_4]

user_qs = [user_1, user_2]

group_query_should_give = [group_1, group_3]
```

Comment: What if a group has *more* items?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem a group can have the users in `user_qs` and more. that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a set of the `Group`s, and then check if these all match, with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

user_qs = User.objects.filter(date_joined__range=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-05'])

Group.objects.filter(
    users__in=user_qs
).alias(
    nusers=Count('users')
).filter(
    nusers=len(user_qs)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Group.objects.filter(users__date_joined__range=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-05'])
```

Comment: This will retrieve all `Group`s for which there is *at least* one user in the given `date_joined` range, it does not require that *all* these users are members.